# how to keep th and tr side by side without covering the whole table space

Tags: jquery, html, css

i  m having trouble in making a simple table where if i have more number of column it should fill the up the table space and if i dont have many number of column it should leave the space blank. for now my table is filling up the whole space

```
<table class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
   <tr> 
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jill</td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th> 
      <td>Jackson</td> 
      <td>Smith</td> 
   </tr>
   <tr> 
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>94</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xtm4c3dk/1/

as you can see it leaving a big space after 2nd th where as i dont want it
I want something like this http://prntscr.com/f8rdg6
where u can see it leaving space in the right side instead of th block
how can i do this please help me

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://jsfiddle.net/xtm4c3dk/2/

Comment: the problem isnt solved .i m looking for a solution where td will have fixed width which will keep adding to thr right if i add more td and if i remove a td it will be removed leaving space in the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the style case `width: 100%` from the table tag. Replace the following style cases

```
table{
  border:1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align:left;
}
th:first-child{
  width: 69px;
}
th:nth-child(2){
  width: 300px;
}
  td{
    width: 149px;
  }
```

with

```
table{
  border:1px solid #000;
  text-align:left;
}
th, td{  
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

Demo [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/xtm4c3dk/14/)

Comment: tyvm faizal seems like that was the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You have given a width to the 2nd child for `300px`. If you reduce the width or remove it the whitespace is reduced or gone. Also check the `td` css width

```
th:nth-child(2){
  width: 300px;
}
```

You can also change the text-align (*left, right, center, absolute*). Check this,

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
}

th:first-child {
  width: 69px;
}

th:nth-child(2) {
  width: 69px;
}

td {
  width: 69px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-responsive" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```